# OutOfMemoryError when doing setImageResource()

Tags: android, imageview, out-of-memory

`ImageView.setImageResource(int id);` is showing `OutOfMemoryError`.
i have a `TableLayout` in that i am adding `TableRow` pragmatically, in each row i'm setting a image, that is already in my projects resource folder, i am referencing those image withe the `resource_id`.

```
private void addItems() {
    table.removeAllViews();
    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(getActivity());
        table.addView(row);

        RelativeLayout profile = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(R.layout.buddyname, null);
        TextView name = (TextView) profile.findViewById(R.id.name);
        name.setText(randomNames[i]);

        ImageView photo = (ImageView) profile.findViewById(R.id.photo);
        photo.setImageResource(randomPhoto[new Random().nextInt(randomPhoto.length - 1)]);
        row.addView(profile);
    }
}
```

each time i am doing `table.removeAllViews();` even then its not working, can i guess is it because the image resource is loading again and again on heap and not clearing the heap, can we reference the previously loaded image, is there any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Buddyname? It seems like it is a contact list. If it is, use the ListView instead. It dynamically loads elements which are visible. 20 Table rows are indeed much.

Comment: you saying is correct, but i have to show all buddies in list and grid, show each time when user change the layout mode, i'm deleting the previous table rows and adding new ones.

Comment: You can easily change between ListView and GridView since they extend AbsListView. Just hold the reference to AbsListView and instantiate GridView or ListView which depends on your setting and set the appropriate adapter. Also, it is possible that you show large avatar images. Use Options.inSampleSize to load scaled Bitmaps. Or if you use resources, make sure the photos are not large.

Comment: but what is the problem with this code, if i click for changeToList and changeToGrid again its showing OutOfMemoryError.
If i comment the line `photo.setImageResource(randomPhoto[new Random().nextInt(randomPhoto.length - 1)]);`, its not making any problem

Comment: It seems that memory management is not so nice in this case and the images are being recycled. What's really wrong here is the bad approach. Never use the logic that can be replaced with AdapterView.